# Firebird 2.5 WIN1258 charset doesnot support Vietnamese?

Tags: character, collation, firebird2.5

I created a table in Firebird 2.5 with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE DMSV (MASV  CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL,
TENSV VARCHAR(120) CHARACTER SET UTF8 NOT NULL,
LOP CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL, 
SDT VARCHAR(11)CHARACTER SET ASCII NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET ASCII,FACE VARCHAR(100)
CHARACTER SET UTF8, PRIMARY KEY (MASV));
```

When i type Vietnamese character into Column "TenSV", the result cannot show the right character, it only shows the "?" character for some special Vietnamese character (ex: "?" for "ể"). I changed the character set to WIN1258 but the problem cannot be solved. What should i do to store the correct character? Thanks a lot for any help. :D

Comment: What is your connection character set, what are you using for displaying the character?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry, This is the first time I post my thread. Thanks for everything. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character (ể) is unicode codepoint U+1EC3, which is not part of [WIN1258](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305151.aspx), and therefor won't be stored (or displayed) using WIN1258. Make sure you use UTF8 for both your connection characterset, database/column characterset and that the application, console or whatever you use for display also supports this character.

See also http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B1ec3

Comment: Thanks for your help, i changed to UTF-8, collate: UNICODE then Firebird can store unicode string. But when i use VB.net send command to execute the sql contains Unicode String, the database store as '?'. Seem something wrongs with .Net Provider when send query string from VB.net to firebird. What should i do to fix it?

Comment: @QuânPhạmTrường Did you specify a connection character set in the .NET provider?